# Linq query with DateTime Comparison is not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

Here the query that does not work as expected:

```
var source     = from conv in AuthRepository.Database.Conversations
                 from msg in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationMessages
                 let pId = playerId
                 let lastReadDate =
                 (
                     from rd in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationReadDates
                     where rd.player_id == pId && rd.conversation_id == conv.id
                     select rd.last_read_date
                 ).FirstOrDefault()
                 // retrieve last message
                 where msg.id ==
                 (
                     from msgs in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationMessages
                     where msgs.conversation_id == conv.id
                     orderby msgs.created descending
                     select msgs.id
                 ).FirstOrDefault()
                 // check if last message was read by player
                 where msg.created > lastReadDate
                 select conv.id;

return await source.CountAsync();
```

In my test "lastReadDate" is supposed to be the default value of DateTime since no last_read_date was found.
But this where clause fail: `where msg.created > lastReadDate`
I already checked that msg.created have a correct value.

But it work as as expected when I split the query in two by retrieving first the lastReadDate part and then use it in the second query like this:

```
var sourceReaddate = from rd in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationReadDates
                                 from conv in AuthRepository.Database.Conversations
                                 where rd.player_id == playerId && rd.conversation_id == conv.id
                                 select rd.last_read_date;
var readDate = await sourceReaddate.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var source = from conv in AuthRepository.Database.Conversations
             from msg in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationMessages
             let pId = playerId
             let lastReadDate = readDate
             // check if player is authorized to see the conversation
             where !pId.HasValue ||
             (
                from auth in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationAuthorization
                let conversation = auth.conversation
                where conversation.id == conv.id && auth.player_id == pId.Value
                select conversation.id
             ).Any()
             // retrieve last message
             where msg.id ==
             (
                from msgs in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationMessages
                where msgs.conversation_id == conv.id
                orderby msgs.created descending
                select msgs.id
             ).FirstOrDefault()
             // check if last message was read by player
             where msg.created > lastReadDate
             where !conv.deleted
             select conv.id;
             
return await source.CountAsync();
```

I suspect this is a bug in EF Core (I use the version 3.1.6) maybe related to this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19052)?
But maybe it's an error from my side. Do you have an idea on what is the problem?

Also here a very disturbing result with this query:

```
var source  = from conv in AuthRepository.Database.Conversations
              from msg in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationMessages
              let pId = playerId
              let lastReadDate =
              (
                 from rd in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationReadDates
                 where rd.player_id == pId && rd.conversation_id == conv.id
                 select rd.last_read_date
              ).FirstOrDefault()
              // retrieve last message
              where msg.id ==
              (
                 from msgs in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationMessages
                 where msgs.conversation_id == conv.id
                 orderby msgs.created descending
                 select msgs.id
              ).FirstOrDefault()
              select new 
              { 
                  msgCreated = msg.created,
                  lastReadDate, 
                  read = msg.created <= lastReadDate, 
                  unread = msg.created > lastReadDate,
                  sup = msg.created > default(DateTime),
                  defEqual = lastReadDate.Equals(default(DateTime)),
                  defSup = lastReadDate > default(DateTime),
                  defInf = lastReadDate < default(DateTime),
              };
              
var result = await source.ToListAsync();
```

Here the result of the above query:

```
{ 
    msgCreated = {07/29/2020 10:48:14}, 
    lastReadDate = {01/01/0001 00:00:00}, 
    read = false, 
    unread = false, 
    sup = true, 
    defEqual = false, 
    defSup = false, 
    defInf = false 
}
```

This is not normal that "read" and "unread" are both evaluated as false. Any idea why?

Comment: First, check the generated SQL against the Linq query. EF Core logs the query at the `information` level.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495686/get-default-value-type-datetime-in-linq-to-sql-query-with-empty-results):

```
var source     = from conv in AuthRepository.Database.Conversations
                 from msg in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationMessages
                 let pId = playerId
                 let lastReadDate =
                 (
                     from rd in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationReadDates
                     where rd.player_id == pId && rd.conversation_id == conv.id
                     select (DateTime?)rd.last_read_date
                 ).FirstOrDefault() ?? default(DateTime)
                 // retrieve last message
                 where msg.id ==
                 (
                     from msgs in AuthRepository.Database.ConversationMessages
                     where msgs.conversation_id == conv.id
                     orderby msgs.created descending
                     select msgs.id
                 ).FirstOrDefault()
                 // check if last message was read by player
                 where msg.created > lastReadDate
                 select conv.id;

return await source.CountAsync();
```